# sklearn predict_proba function only returns probability of 1 (binary classification)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a school project in Machine Learning where i need to create a model for a kaggle [course](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/predict-student-performance-from-game-play).

I create a DecisionTreeClassifier for each question (1-18) and when i try execute each model on the test data and i lookup at the `predict_proba` function it doesn't results in like [0.73, 0.27] but instead only [0, 1] etc... It makes impossible a threshold adjustment.

How I fit each tree :

```py
    values_train = df_group.loc[:, ~df_group.columns.isin(["level_group", "correct"])]

    dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    dt.fit(X=values_train, y=df_group["correct"])
```

Prediction and result :

```py
trees["1_0-4"].predict_proba(tests[0])

array([[0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Any idea why i have this weird behaviour (or if it's normal) ? Also i have an accuracy of 100% for my training part and 66% for the test data.

I tried to manipulate the columns or the data by adding `.values` but it changes nothingt

Comment: i checked this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68009571/naive-gaussian-predict-probability-only-returns-0-or-1?rq=2

Seems it may be an overfitting but i'm still searching why and how to repair it

Answer (score 0):

This is due to some overfitting. I used GridSearchCV to adjust my hyperparameters (max_depth in particular) and now it's far better